# Загрузка данных в SOLR через HTTP C#

Tags: c#, .net, solr

Есть задача - хранение и поиск простых текстовых документов с использованием solr

Создав коллекцию pogovorki, пишу команду:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/pogovorki/update?commit=true" --data-binary @D:/test01.json -H 'Content-type:application/json'
```

данные загружаются.

Как сделать этот же запрос через http ?

запрос в браузере

`http://localhost:8983/solr/pogovorki/update?commit=true" --data-binary @D:/test01.json -H 'Content-type:application/json`

Выполняется, но данные не заполняет.

Реализую это при помощи Visual Studio 2017

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8983/solr/pogovorki/update/update?commit=true" --data-binary @D:/test01.json -H 'Content-type:application/json"); request.ContentType = "application/json"; request.Method = "POST";
```

но также не получаю результат...

Нужно реализовать загрузку файлов в solr через openFileDialog. Но никак не могу отправить корректный HTTP запрос через браузер и Visual Studio. Только через командную строку грузит при помощи curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итоговый результат публикую:
ar request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8983/solr/pogovorki/update?commit=true");
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";

```
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            var json = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test01.json");
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

[--data-binary](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-binary) - это параметр самого curl.

Браузер его не понимает, поэтому нет смысла передавать его в адресной строке. Тем более из браузера уйдет запрос GET, а нужен явно POST.

`WebRequest` тоже не понимает этот параметр. Я так понимаю, его заменой является как раз `request.Method = "POST"`.

---

[-H](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H) - параметр curl, позволяющий задать заголовки.

В браузере хедеры нельзя задать в адресной строке.

В классе `WebRequest` для некоторых заголовков есть отдельные свойства, как например, `request.ContentType = "application/json";`. Дополнительные заголовки можно добавить в свойство `Headers`.

---

curl сам читает файл и передаёт его. Нам нужно прочитать данные из файла и передать в поток.

Итого, это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8983/solr/pogovorki/update/update?commit=true");
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";


using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test01.json");
    streamWriter.Write(json);
}

using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Эх ... но теперь на строчку using (var response = request.GetResponse()) вылетает Exeption - 404 ошибка - не найден.... Как же  всё таки написать то....

Comment: @Vasilenko - в адресе `update` один или два раза?

Comment: @Alexandr Petrov.Действительно нужно было один раз update. Спасибо большое за помощь! Это работает!